# how to put a post link into CDetailview in Yii

Tags: yii

i have a view page using CDetailView,

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
        'label'=>'Keyword',
        'type'=>'html',
        'value'=>getKeywordsHtml($model),
    ),
)); ?>
```

the function getKeywordsHtml() is defined in same file as below.

```
<?php
function getKeywordsHtml($model)
{
    $keywordsHtml='';

    foreach ($model->keywords as $keyword)
    {
        $keywordsHtml = $keywordsHtml.
                        CHtml::link($keyword->name,array('keyword/view', 'id'=>$keyword->id)).

                        CHtml::link(' [del] ',
                            array('problem/delkeyword', 'id'=>$model->id, 'kid'=>$keyword->id), 
                            array(
                                'submit'=>array(
                                    '/problem/delkeyword',
                                    'id'=>$model->id, 
                                    'kid'=>$keyword->id
                                ),
                            'class' => 'delete',
                            'confirm'=>'Are you sure?'
                            )
                        ).'<br>';
    }
    return $keywordsHtml;           
}
?>
```

I want the page to show the keyword with a del link beside it.

now the link works fine. it goes to the /delkeyword&id=1, but the confirm window didn't work. so it the post doesn't work.

I tried the following code outside the detail widget, it works fine.

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::link('keyword 1',array('keyword/view','id'=>1)).CHtml::link(' [del] ',array('problem/delkeyword','id'=>1, 'kid'=>1), array('submit'=>array('/problem/delkeyword', 'id'=>1, 'kid'=>1),'class' => 'delete','confirm'=>'Are you sure?')).'<br>';
?>
```

And the html output

work outside CDetailview：
     [del]  
not work in CDetailview：
     [del]

So how should i modify my code?

Comment: How does the html output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this into the delete part

```
    CHtml::link("Delete", '#', array(
'submit'=>array('problem/delkeyword', 'id'=>$model->id, 'kid'=>$keyword->id), 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete?'));
```

Comment: nothing happen， but goes to http://localhost/Math_yii/index.php?r=problem/view&id=1#